# Boot menu with retropi or desktop

Tags: boot, retropie

I get a pi 4b and i installed raspbian on it.
The main purposes for this pi is:

- netflix
- retropi

So i installed raspbian and retropi soft on raspbian. Then i found a way to use netflix on chromium.
I have set the pi to direclty boot with emulationstation

No i want to know if it possible to have a boot menu whith this 2 possibilities:

- boot emulationstation
- boot raspbian desktop

thanks

Comment: I can see you have tried to make an edit under a new account. Can you please merge these accounts. Please see this [section](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) of the [help](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) page on how to do this.

Comment: Isn't that what NOOBS is for?